# BSOD - WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR - WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I saw in a previous post an issue similar to my own, however the answer given was very specific to the OP's situation ([BSOD - Win8_driver_fault on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1030591/bsod-win8-driver-fault-on-windows-10)).  I too am getting a WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR with the WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT tag, though I'm running on Windows 10.  I agree that I probably have a bad driver somewhere, but I'm wondering how to determine which driver is at fault? Here is the WinDbg information from the two most recent minidumps:  (Thanks in advance!

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\zcoffin\Desktop\Minidump\010917-9796-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 14393 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 14393.576.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`10a8a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`10d8f060
Debug session time: Mon Jan  9 17:26:27.922 2017 (UTC - 6:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 23:07:57.136
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..............
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
...............................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 124, {0, ffffce85d0822028, be000000, 800400}

Probably caused by : GenuineIntel

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffce85d0822028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000800400, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.576 (rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Precision 7510

SYSTEM_SKU:  06D9

BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.4.8

BIOS_DATE:  03/15/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  0M91XC

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffce85d0822028

BUGCHECK_P3: be000000

BUGCHECK_P4: 800400

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a98

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 82'00000000 (cache) 82'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  KT447

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  01-18-2017 10:18:54.0023

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8a01`eda8a6f8 fffff800`10a4b27f : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 ffffce85`d0822028 00000000`be000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff8a01`eda8a700 fffff800`10cb533c : ffffce85`d0822028 ffffce85`d01a7790 ffffce85`d01a7790 ffffce85`d01a7790 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xcf
ffff8a01`eda8a740 fffff800`10a4b76c : 00000000`00000728 00000000`00000003 ffff8a01`eda8ab30 00000000`00000000 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x258
ffff8a01`eda8a7a0 fffff800`10a4bac4 : ffffce85`00000010 ffffce85`d01a7790 ffff8a01`eda8a948 ffffce85`d01a7790 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x50
ffff8a01`eda8a8f0 fffff800`10a4b9ae : ffffce85`d00f2d20 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xe8
ffff8a01`eda8a940 fffff800`10a4bbee : 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xda
ffff8a01`eda8a980 fffff800`10a4bd70 : ffffce85`d00f2d20 ffff8a01`eda8abb0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xce
ffff8a01`eda8a9b0 fffff800`10bde5fb : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
ffff8a01`eda8a9e0 fffff800`10bde384 : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`10bde303 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
ffff8a01`eda8ab20 fffff80a`21381348 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x184
ffff8a01`edaab7d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : intelppm!MWaitIdle+0x18


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8a3debe308db92f808172b280ea37d168a0241fb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  a3d0fc6f45f5a5bf0f4efdb757bea1ce8adf8158

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  79568083e9b8a322b030a6184dee2335a8d0d817

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

TARGET_TIME:  2017-01-09T23:26:27.000Z

OSBUILD:  14393

OSSERVICEPACK:  576

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-12-09 03:23:02

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  161208-2252

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release_inmarket

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.576

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 47c

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_mae

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {7c95de0c-286c-8226-45c2-422b4de101d6}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------


            Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 AMD64
            Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


            Loading Dump File [C:\Users\zcoffin\Desktop\Minidump\011317-7734-01.dmp]
            Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

            Symbol search path is: srv*
            Executable search path is: 
            Windows 10 Kernel Version 14393 MP (8 procs) Free x64
            Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
            Built by: 14393.693.amd64fre.rs1_release.161220-1747
            Machine Name:
            Kernel base = 0xfffff801`23601000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`23906060
            Debug session time: Fri Jan 13 20:14:27.980 2017 (UTC - 6:00)
            System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:30.674
            Loading Kernel Symbols
            ...............................................................
            ................................................................
            ................................................................
            .....
            Loading User Symbols
            Loading unloaded module list
            ............
            *******************************************************************************
            *                                                                             *
            *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
            *                                                                             *
            *******************************************************************************

            Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

            BugCheck 124, {0, ffffb68015e43028, be000000, 800400}

            Probably caused by : GenuineIntel

            Followup:     MachineOwner
            ---------

            7: kd> !analyze -v
            *******************************************************************************
            *                                                                             *
            *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
            *                                                                             *
            *******************************************************************************

            WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
            A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
            source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
            WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
            Arguments:
            Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
            Arg2: ffffb68015e43028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
            Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
            Arg4: 0000000000800400, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

            Debugging Details:
            ------------------


            DUMP_CLASS: 1

            DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

            BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.693 (rs1_release.161220-1747)

            SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

            SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Precision 7510

            SYSTEM_SKU:  06D9

            BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.

            BIOS_VERSION:  1.4.8

            BIOS_DATE:  03/15/2016

            BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

            BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  0M91XC

            BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

            DUMP_TYPE:  2

            BUGCHECK_P1: 0

            BUGCHECK_P2: ffffb68015e43028

            BUGCHECK_P3: be000000

            BUGCHECK_P4: 800400

            BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

            CPU_COUNT: 8

            CPU_MHZ: a98

            CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

            CPU_FAMILY: 6

            CPU_MODEL: 5e

            CPU_STEPPING: 3

            CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 82'00000000 (cache) 82'00000000 (init)

            CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

            DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

            PROCESS_NAME:  System

            CURRENT_IRQL:  f

            ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  KT447

            ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  01-18-2017 10:13:57.0972

            ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

            STACK_TEXT:  
            ffffdb01`0808a6f8 fffff801`23e5727f : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 ffffb680`15e43028 00000000`be000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
            ffffdb01`0808a700 fffff801`2382c34c : ffffb680`15e43028 ffffb680`157a5d50 ffffb680`157a5d50 ffffb680`157a5d50 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xcf
            ffffdb01`0808a740 fffff801`23e5776c : 00000000`00000728 00000000`00000007 ffffdb01`0808ab30 00000000`00000000 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x258
            ffffdb01`0808a7a0 fffff801`23e57ac4 : ffffb680`00000010 ffffb680`157a5d50 ffffdb01`0808a948 ffffb680`157a5d50 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x50
            ffffdb01`0808a8f0 fffff801`23e579ae : ffffb680`156f2fe0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000007 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xe8
            ffffdb01`0808a940 fffff801`23e57bee : 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xda
            ffffdb01`0808a980 fffff801`23e57d70 : ffffb680`156f2fe0 ffffdb01`0808abb0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xce
            ffffdb01`0808a9b0 fffff801`237555fb : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
            ffffdb01`0808a9e0 fffff801`23755384 : 00000000`00000000 fffff801`23755303 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
            ffffdb01`0808ab20 fffff808`6d8c1348 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x184
            ffffdb01`080ab7d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : intelppm!MWaitIdle+0x18


            STACK_COMMAND:  kb

            THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  8a3debe308db92f808172b280ea37d168a0241fb

            THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  a3d0fc6f45f5a5bf0f4efdb757bea1ce8adf8158

            THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  79568083e9b8a322b030a6184dee2335a8d0d817

            FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

            MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

            IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

            DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

            FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

            BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

            PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

            TARGET_TIME:  2017-01-14T02:14:27.000Z

            OSBUILD:  14393

            OSSERVICEPACK:  693

            SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

            OS_REVISION: 0

            SUITE_MASK:  272

            PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

            OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

            OSNAME:  Windows 10

            OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

            OS_LOCALE:  

            USER_LCID:  0

            OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-12-21 00:50:57

            BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  161220-1747

            BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release

            BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.693

            ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 473

            ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

            FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_mae

            FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {7c95de0c-286c-8226-45c2-422b4de101d6}

            Followup:     MachineOwner
            ---------
```

Here's some more info, !errrec ffffce85d0822028.  I really can't make anything out of this...

```
3: kd> !errrec ffffce85d0822028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffce85d0822028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d26a0de82d78cf
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/9/2017 23:26:27 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffce85d08220a8
Section       @ ffffce85d0822180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000506e3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000003

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffce85d08220f0
Section       @ ffffce85d0822240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000003
CPU Id        : e3 06 05 00 00 08 10 03 - ff fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffce85d0822240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffce85d0822138
Section       @ ffffce85d08222c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal timer (Proc 3 Bank 4)
    Status      : 0xbe00000000800400
    Address     : 0xfffff80010bddf15
    Misc.       : 0xfffff80010bddf15
```

Comment: use **!errrec ffffce85d0822028** (value from arg2) to see more details

Comment: I see those added details, but i'm not seeing anything immediately indicating the problem driver... thoughts?  I've checked this on multiple minidumps of the same problem; it seems that the Error : Internal timer is not always on the same Proc or Bank...

Comment: I'm guessing this one is actually a hardware problem though... it seems to be very inconsistent. Sometimes it will last for a few hours, other times it will last for only ten minutes before throwing BSOD. I'm thinking there's something (CPU perhaps) that physically gets warmed up and comes partially out of its socket, not entirely but enough to throw an error. I'm thinking of booting to different drive and running some burn-in test like prime95.

Comment: yeah, this is some internal timer of the CPU. test the CPU with a stress test tool (prime95) and look if you get failures.