# System service exception with windows 10 BSOD with theThinkpad p52

Tags: windows, bsod

I have been getting the BSOD regularly on the ThinkPad p52. The details are shown below. Can someone kindly help me deal with this issue ?

[image]

I have ran the tests from the Lenovo solution center and there was no errors.

[image]

Here is the result of my dump file.

```
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff801438b7b98, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd204b19de540, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  20M9001GMX

SYSTEM_SKU:  LENOVO_MT_20M9_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad P52

SYSTEM_VERSION:  ThinkPad P52

BIOS_VENDOR:  LENOVO

BIOS_VERSION:  N2CET35W (1.18 )

BIOS_DATE:  12/14/2018

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  20M9001GMX

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  SDK0J40697 WIN

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff801438b7b98

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd204b19de540

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!HvpGetCellPaged+68
fffff801`438b7b98 488b4808        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rax+8]

CONTEXT:  ffffd204b19de540 -- (.cxr 0xffffd204b19de540)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffffd204b19defb0 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=000000000c000003 rsi=ffffd60ae403b000 rdi=ffffd60ae403b000
rip=fffff801438b7b98 rsp=ffffd204b19def38 rbp=ffffd204b19df011
 r8=ffffd60ae4302000  r9=0000000000000060 r10=0000000000000003
r11=0000000000000003 r12=ffffd60afa421268 r13=0000000000000000
r14=00000000c0000034 r15=000001d8ec30380c
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
nt!HvpGetCellPaged+0x68:
fffff801`438b7b98 488b4808        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rax+8] ds:002b:00000000`00000008=????????????????
Resetting default scope

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B_c0000005

CPU_COUNT: c

CPU_MHZ: 8a0

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: a

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,a,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 96'00000000 (cache) 96'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  Registry

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-4QSLGJH

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  02-19-2019 21:12:09.0248

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18317.1001 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8014388fe6a to fffff801438b7b98

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd204`b19def38 fffff801`4388fe6a : 00000000`03a1b352 00000000`c6a90461 00000000`00000001 ffffd60a`fa421268 : nt!HvpGetCellPaged+0x68
ffffd204`b19def40 fffff801`43912b1e : ffffd60a`fa421268 ffffd204`b19df1a0 ffffd204`b19df140 ffffd204`b19df180 : nt!CmpWalkOneLevel+0x4ba
ffffd204`b19df060 fffff801`4391201a : 00000000`0000001c ffffd204`b19df380 ffffd204`b19df350 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpDoParseKey+0x4ce
ffffd204`b19df2d0 fffff801`43933fb9 : fffff801`43911db0 ffffd60a`00000000 ffffc085`5c92da90 ffffc085`00020001 : nt!CmpParseKey+0x26a
ffffd204`b19df460 fffff801`439325bf : ffffc085`5c92da00 ffffd204`b19df6c8 00000000`00000040 ffffc085`536ff560 : nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x719
ffffd204`b19df630 fffff801`43930c48 : 00000000`00000001 ffffc085`536ff560 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx+0x1df
ffffd204`b19df770 fffff801`4393099f : 00000296`5889e6a8 fffff801`43204ae6 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000005c : nt!CmOpenKey+0x298
ffffd204`b19df9c0 fffff801`4345e685 : 00000296`59560290 ffffd204`b19dfa80 ffffc085`536cfc00 00000296`593175f0 : nt!NtOpenKeyEx+0xf
ffffd204`b19dfa00 00007ffc`b20319a4 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
000000ba`b5b7c828 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`b20319a4


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  17adaa13f1ddbba25dd8241c2904b54a3a6d375e

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  136dcda49ec556d8f097e05ee1ff9d9b0d53d6a1

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  9f457f347057f10e1df248e166a3e95e6570ecfe

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!HvpGetCellPaged+68
fffff801`438b7b98 488b4808        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rax+8]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  8488b48

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!HvpGetCellPaged+68

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17763.316

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffd204b19de540 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  68

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_c0000005_nt!HvpGetCellPaged

BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_c0000005_nt!HvpGetCellPaged

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x3B_c0000005_nt!HvpGetCellPaged

TARGET_TIME:  2019-02-19T14:56:45.000Z

OSBUILD:  17763

OSSERVICEPACK:  316

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180914-1434

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  5576

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_c0000005_nt!hvpgetcellpaged

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {32f4db97-5bc1-37be-caf3-746cdc554a0b}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

And a direct screenshot
[image]

Here are the results from the memTest86

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I enabled verifier, I got the DRIVER_DETECTED_VIOLATION on Boot up. To mitigate, I went into safe mode and deleted the current settings of the verifier.

[image]

When I used the sfc /scannow, there was no errors.
[image]

Please let me know what else I can support to further clarify the issue

Comment: Try this software, see if it reveals any more details of the bsod....https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: @Moab the screenshot above is from that software

Comment: The you will have to further debugging of the dump files using Microsoft tools....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315263/how-to-read-the-small-memory-dump-file-that-is-created-by-windows-if-a

Comment: Run memory test [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) and post the result log.

Comment: @harrymc kindly check the uploaded screenshots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BSOD - Win8\_driver\_fault on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1030591/bsod-win8-driver-fault-on-windows-10)

Comment: If this is a new issue verify all drivers are updated, pay attention to network devices, but honestly really any device driver could be at fault.  Be sure to avoid any driver that isn’t specifically marked as being compatible with the version of Windows 10 your using (1809).  Your BSOD appears to be specifically caused by a device driver

Comment: @Ramhound Can you recommend a tool that I can check all the drivers are working together and their compatibilities flow together? free or paid is okay.

Comment: @Matthew - The best tool is, yourself, and manually verifying your drivers.  You don’t have that many devices.

Comment: @Ramhound if I knew how to do that, given that I knew it even existed in the first place I wouldn't have asked :D So do you mean, for example, open device manager? right click update ? or what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound you also marked this as a duplicate, wherein my question does that indicate it is a win_8_driver fault ? I would like to know so I can also see that win_8_drive fault. Because I did not know I have a win_8_fault.

Comment: @Matthew - “DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT” came directly from your question body.  As for identifying your devices, Lenovo provides a list of devices and therr drivers.  I would use that list to find current drivers for each device.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier) is the tool Microsoft recommended to one of their users who had a similar BSOD.  If your actually completely lost that might point you in a direction so you can provide information so an answer can be submitted

Comment: No errors found by MemTest86, which means that this is likely not a hardware error and we can concentrate on software. The tool recommended by @Ramhound is useful. I would also recommend [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a-21.html).

Comment: MemTestx86 rules out memory but not a bad WiFi module or BT module or sound card.  Microsoft is aggressively making changes to drivers on Windows 10, there are sometimes drivers for versions before X and after Y (Killer Networking Adapters)

Comment: @Ramhound Verifier has caused me hell. Could not boot up my computer without DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VOILATION BSOD, so I went into safe mode, disable and now it worked again. Updated Question. Kindy advise

Comment: @harrymc there was no errors in the sfc /scannow, but computer driver violation BSOD came up when running the veriifer. Updated quesiton

Comment: You got the BSOD due to running the tool, right, but what exactly did you disable in safe mode?  Was a mini dump created?

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @Matthew  Have you run the Lenovo System Update utility?  It will indicate the latest drivers and BIOS updates.  Link to Canada support but should work with other English installs  https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/downloads/ds012808

Comment: @Ramhound check solution below

Comment: @harrymc check solution below

Comment: @DaveM check solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a motherboard issue.
Submitted a ticket to Lenovo support online, I got a call within 3 working days that support I.T is coming over to where I am to check the computer.
Replaced hardware parts and the system has passed all the tests mentioned in the comment section above. All free of charge as it was still under warranty.

[image]